# Convert Php Curl Function to Perl

Tags: perl, curl

It would be great if someone could help convert this function from Php to Perl, basically this function is meant to get contents of a https url. Right now I'm not good with Perl, I haven't learnt on how to use cURL just yet.

```
function curl_get_content($url)
                    {
                    $handle = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); 
                    $data = curl_exec($handle);
                    curl_close($handle);
                    return $data;
                    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

I attempted to use this

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });  
 my $header = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $URL);  
 my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $URL, $header);  
 my $response = $ua->request($request);  
 if ($response->is_success){  
     print "URL:$URL\nHeaders:\n";  
     print $response->headers_as_string;  
 }elsif ($response->is_error){  
     print "Error:$URL\n";  
     print $response->error_as_HTML;  
 }
```

But it keeps giving me server error: 500.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.15/lib/WWW/Curl.pm

Comment: You can also do that with LWP.

Comment: I did try with LWP, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to, unless I'm doing it wrong?                                                                                            `sub getContent {
    my ($URL) = @_; 
    my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new(env_proxy => 0,keep_alive => 1, timeout => 30);  
    my $header = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $URL);  
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $URL, $header);  
    my $response = $agent->request($request); 
    return $response; 
}`

Comment: @user2524169: Why don't you add your attempt to your question?  Multi-line code in a comment is a PITA to read (which is why i typically don't bother :P ), and there might be a simple fix for what you already have.

Comment: Are there any SSL-options you need to set? If not and you just want the contents as a string, you can simply use LWP::Simple: `use LWP::Simple; print get("https://github.com");`

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that you're not setting the headers correctly so when the server is receiving your request and trying to process the headers, it's not understanding the content and just giving up (giving you the 500 error.)  In your code, you're setting `$header` to a [`HTTP::Request`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aRequest) object but that should actually be a [`HTTP::Headers`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aHeaders) object.  Set that to:

```
my $header = HTTP::Headers->new();
$header->header( 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' ); # set content-type to what you need
# you can add additional headers if needed
```